# Force file download in php not working

Tags: php, file

I have this script to force file download in php but its not working. the file still opens on the page. Help me figure out what is wrong.

```
<?php

$orderid=sql_prep($_GET['oid']);

if(isset($_POST['file'])){

    $file = $_POST['file'];

    header("Content-Description: File Transfer"); 
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream"); 
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
    readfile('attachments/'.$orderid.'/user/'.$file);
}
?>

<form action="" method="POST" name="dwnld" >
  <input name="file" value="<?php echo $file['filekey']; ?>" type="hidden">
  <button type="submit"> <?php echo $file['filename']; ?> </button>
</form>
```

Comment: `die()` after `readfile()`. NO OUTPUT after sending file

Comment: is it solved, yet?

Comment: is it only pdf files? or any files type

Comment: all, even odt files.

Comment: I will post answer I have test it and works

Comment: array(7) { ["id"]=> string(2) "16" ["userid"]=> string(2) "12" ["orderid"]=> string(2) "43" ["date"]=> string(19) "2016-04-06 18:34:32" ["filename"]=> string(23) "About Lenzi Africa.docx" ["filetitle"]=> string(12) "Attachment 0" ["filekey"]=> string(37) "fb68271f3fe1fc66151ca7c865db6ff1.docx" }

Comment: Its in a while loop so that is one of the $files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108453/discussion-between-maytham-mahtyam-and-kakali).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are testing this in firefox or google chrome. Also you are trying to download pdf or txt file I hope.
In google chrome [Adobe acrobot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adobe-acrobat/efaidnbmnnnibpcajpcglclefindmkaj?hl=en) and in firefox [adobe reader](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/use-adobe-reader-plugin-view-or-download-pdf-files) plugins are preinstalled.

So there is nothing to do with php code to download. Your code is correct. 
You can test it by disabling acrobot in google chrome. for doing so visit chrome://plugins/ in your chrome. then disable **Chrome PDF Viewer** . Then browse the download link.

Comment: so how can i prevent the user from seeing this if they have acrobot and reader preinstalled?